# Best datastructure for a list with metadata

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a number of objects I want to keep together, plus a bit of metadata about them. For example, a number of files plus the folder they came from.

The obvious way to collecting the objects is a list, but that doesn't have a good way to add the metadata. What's a good/pythonic way to do this?

1. If I wanted to just access the collection through the metadata, I
   could use a dictionary, but I do need to have the metadata available
   while passing around the list. So it needs to be saved with the collection.
2. I can make my own class to do it, but that seems lots of unnecessary
   boilerplate for something small like that.
3. I can't add the metadata as an attribute to the list `data_list.meta = 'something'`. I can subclass list and then do it, but that seems inelegant and not particularly discoverable.
   Basically a better version of 2., but it still seems there ougth to be a better way.
4. Another option would be dataclass, with one attribute for the
   metadata and one for the list. But again, that seems like a lot of
   effort for something simple.

Ideally, I'd like something along the lines of namedtuple, something fast and simple, but I'm not aware of anything like that. What is the best solution here?

Comment: Possibly a dictionary containing another dictionary for metadata and a list for your objects as values?

Comment: The question is tagged `python` and you say you'd like *"something along the lines of namedtuple, something fast and simple, but I'm not aware of anything like that"*. But `namedtuple` is Python!

Comment: what's wrong about making your own class for it? option 2) sounds very reasonable

Comment: @JPI93 That's a solution, but it seems more cumbersome than just a new class.
@kaya3 `namedtuple` is Python, that's why I gave it as an example, but it doesn't actually do what I want.
@Stef Making a new class is workable, but this strikes me as a problem someone probably already solved more elegantly. If that's not the case, then that's what I'll go with.

Comment: @BurnNote Agreed. To be honest I'd probably just use a class to tackle this one personally. Only thought the nested dict and list solution worth suggesting as you expressed a disinclination towards writing a class to handle this in your original question.